# import module failed

Tags: python, module

The version I used is python2.7, error occurs when I used script, but it works in command line.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
```

and the errors:

```
ravjqpejcnngpig.eqo/re/fgh/ocr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tsTclntTW.py", line 5, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from zope.interface import Interface
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope.interface-4.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in <module>
    self.callbacks.append(callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 701, in Environment

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 96, in get_supported_platform
    distutils.util.get_platform() normally reports the minimum version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 222, in get_build_platform
    # fallback for MacPorts
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/util.py", line 65, in get_platform
    osname = string.lower(osname)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lower'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 18, in <module>
    import problem_report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/multipart.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 14, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/quoprimime.py", line 48, in <module>
    from string import hexdigits
ImportError: cannot import name hexdigits

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tsTclntTW.py", line 5, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from zope.interface import Interface
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope.interface-4.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in <module>
    self.callbacks.append(callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 701, in Environment

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 96, in get_supported_platform
    distutils.util.get_platform() normally reports the minimum version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 222, in get_build_platform
    # fallback for MacPorts
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/util.py", line 65, in get_platform
    osname = string.lower(osname)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I have re-installed the Python I used and it doesn't work, I'm in Ubuntu 12.04. Also I have do

```
grep ravjqpejcnngpig.eqo/re/fgh/ocr . -R -n
```

under `/usr/lib/python2.7` but nothing returned.

Comment: `ravjqpejcnngpig.eqo/re/fgh/ocr` looks like output from `tsTclntTW.py`, it has nothing to do with your error.  It's part of the Python Challenge, which you appear to be doing.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Yes, it's  stupid to name my own script as 'string.py'. and indeed I was doing the python challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you have a module named `string` in your project, and it shadows the library module of the same name.

---

EDIT:  To find out, add this to your script just before the failing import statement:

```
import string
print string.__file__
```

Comment: @kyon Are you sure? The traceback is almost *yelling* that the `string` module isn't the stdlib `string` module. Double check that in your directory you're running this, there isn't a `string.py`

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I find a string.py in my directory. Thanks a lot!